# iOS Time Profiler # of Methods Execution

Tags: ios, performance, profiler

I have been trying to time profile an application. Once done, I search for a symbol or an function. If the symbol is called only 2 times, I can see it in a stack trace, somewhere down in the tree after main. However, if I check the Top Function box, I see that symbol a lot many times. I am confused now. So how may I know that a function or a method is called "x" number of times, so that I may calculate the total execution time for that function or method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: + Welcome to SO! There's a better and simpler way to see what's taking time in your program, that doesn't involve calculating or measuring functions. [*Check it out.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)

Comment: @Mike, thank you. I am looking for a way to do it on iPhone, using instruments.